# How do I make a sidebar slide-in from the right on button click?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am sorry, I can't show you the full code, but here's what I can show:

```js
handleSidebar(el) {
  const mainContainer = el.currentTarget.closest('.navbar__main-container');
  const sidebarWrapper = mainContainer.querySelector('.navbar__sidebar-wrapper');
  const navbarWrapper = sidebarWrapper.querySelector('.navbar__sidebar');
  mainContainer.classList.toggle('show')
  sidebarWrapper.classList.toggle('show')
  navbarWrapper.classList.toggle('show')
}
```

```css
.navbar__main-container {
  position: relative;
  &.show {
    height: 100vh;
  }
}

.navbar__sidebar-wrapper {
  display: none;
  &.show {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    background-color: #1D1D1D33;
    position: absolute;
    top: 64px;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: calc(100% - 64px);
    z-index: 10000;
  }
  & .navbar__sidebar {
    position: relative;
    left: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: flex-start;
    padding: 32px;
    gap: 8px;
    width: 375px;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: tokens.$color-bg-white;
    flex: none;
    order: 1;
    flex-grow: 0;
    transition: left 1s;
    &.show {
      left: 0;
      transition: left 1s;
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="navbar__main-container">
  <div class="navbar__container">...</div>
  <div class="navbar__sidebar-wrapper">
    <div class="navbar__sidebar"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The `.navbar__container` element is the actual navbar, whereas the `.navbar__sidebar-wrapper` holds the sidebar (`.navbar__sidebar`), and is used for the background color.

There's a burger button on the navbar. On click, class `show` is added to `navbar__main-container`, `navbar__sidebar-wrapper` and `navbar__sidebar`. On `navbar__main-container`, the `show` class adds the `height 100vh`. On `navbar__sidebar-wrapper`, the `show` class makes the element appear again by changing the display from `none` to `flex`, and on `navbar__sidebar`, it changes the `left` from `100%` to `0`, thereby it should cause the element to slide in, and it does if you check in/off the `left` style from inspect tools, but by just clicking the button, the sidebar (`.navbar__sidebar`) just appears without any transition.

I think the fact that the sidebar (`navbar__sidebar`) is inside an element wrapper that appears with instantly via `display: none` -> `flex` is probably what's causing this issue, but I am not sure. Probably when the `navbar__sidebar-wrapper` appears, the `transition` is canceled, or something like that?

How else can I make it work? Do you have any ideas?

Please do not ask me to give a reproduction snippet. The rest of the code is too big, too irrelevant to this one particular functionality that I want to achieve, and it contains company information I would rather not share. I have given you the relevant part of the code.

Thanks in advance.

I tried making the `navbar__sidebar` `position absolute`, but it did not make a difference.
I tried using  `transform: translateX(0)` and  `transform: translateX(100%);` to hide/show the sidebar, but it did not work again. The slide-in `transition` is not working.

The function that handles the sidebar:

```
 handleSidebar(el) { 
    const mainContainer = el.currentTarget.closest('.navbar__main-container');
    const sidebarWrapper = mainContainer.querySelector('.navbar__sidebar-wrapper');
    const navbarWrapper = sidebarWrapper.querySelector('.navbar__sidebar');
    mainContainer.classList.toggle('show')
    sidebarWrapper.classList.toggle('show')
    navbarWrapper.classList.toggle('show')
  }
```

The function is invoked when you click the burger icon on the menu.

Here is a screenshot of the `navbar` + the `sidebar`. You can see the slightly transparent background that appears that covers the rest of the screen height.

[image: screen shot]

Comment: I already made it work.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function sidebarOpen () {
  document.getElementsByClassName('navbar__sidebar')[0].classList.add('show');
}
```

```css
.navbar__container {
  text-align: right;
}
.navbar__sidebar {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: -301px;
  width: 300px;
  background-color: white;
  z-index: 99;
  transition: left 1s;
  height: 100vh;
  border-right: 1px solid red;
}
.navbar__sidebar.show {
  left: 0px
}
```

```html
<div class="navbar__main-container">
  <div class="navbar__container"><button onClick="sidebarOpen()">Open sidebar</button></div>
  <div class="navbar__sidebar-wrapper">
    <div class="navbar__sidebar">Sidebar</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Hope this is what you are looking for

Comment: But the issue here is that there is no background-color. The background color is a key part, and is why I have a `navbar__sidebar-wrapper`. On Click, a slightly transparent BG color should cover the entire screen's height minus the navbar, and the sidebar should slide in on top of it.

Comment: I've updated the question to include a screenshot.

Comment: I already resolved it.